# Generate a random image on page load

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, random, onload

I am trying to pull a random image on load with a JavaScript function on my site and set it as the body background-image.

I’ve been searching and trying to piece together a solution but have been unsuccessful.

Here is what I have,

```
function chatimgset() {  
//declare an array
var randomImage = new Array();  
  
//insert the URL of images in array  
randomImage[0] = "image.png";  
randomImage[1] = "image 2.png";  
randomImage[2] = "image 3.png";  
randomImage[3] = "image 4.png ";  
randomImage[4] = "image 5.png";    
  
//generate a number 
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.length);  
  
//return the images generated by number 
return  
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("background-image", "'"+randomImage[number]+"'");
}
```

Where did I go wrong on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set [background image](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp) on body you need something like this

> document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img_tree.png')";

So try this

```
function chatimgset() {
    //declare an array
    var randomImage = new Array();

    //insert the URL of images in array  
    randomImage[0] = "image.png";
    randomImage[1] = "image 2.png";
    randomImage[2] = "image 3.png";
    randomImage[3] = "image 4.png ";
    randomImage[4] = "image 5.png";

    //generate a number 
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImage.length);

    //return the images generated by number 
    return randomImage[number];
}
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + chatimgset() + "')";
```

Comment: Ok so this worked after I used the ```<script>``` tags on the main HTML document with ```document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + chatimgset() + "')";``` in between. Apparently trying to use ```<body onload=“function()”>``` was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the style's `background-image` property, not the `background-image` attribute. So this is what you should write:

```
function chatimgset() {
  //declare an array
  var randomImage = new Array();

  //insert the URL of images in array  
  randomImage[0] = "image.png";
  randomImage[1] = "image 2.png";
  randomImage[2] = "image 3.png";
  randomImage[3] = "image 4.png ";
  randomImage[4] = "image 5.png";

  //generate a number 
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImage.length);

  //return the images generated by number 
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundImage = `url('${randomImage[number]}')`;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I changed it but it still isn’t working for me. I am using, ```<body onload=“chatimgset()”>``` Should I be doing something different?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add the `url(...)` part.